# Android bitmap with transparent region

Tags: android, bitmap

How can I set a polygon (which would be specified by a collection of points) to transparent using a PNG image on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, you would have to first get a reference to the resource from a `BitmapFactory`:

```
Bitmap my_image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.[your_image]);
```

Then, you would have to use the `setPixels()`method to define the region on the PNG that are to be made transparent.  Transparency, I believe, is achieved my setting the pixel `Color` to 0.

Deriving the polygon would be some computation that you would have to do in your application, followed by passing the dimensions of the polygon into the `setPixels()` method.  See [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) taken from the Android developer documents for an idea on how to use the `setPixels()` method.

Note that this assumes that your PNG file is **mutable**.  You will get an `IllegalStateException` otherwise.

---

### Deriving The Area for an N-Sided Polygon

This is where your problem gets significantly more challenging.  Since you cannot use conventional area formulas (as the area has nothing to do with this example, but rather where the vertices are located), you must figure out a way to calculate the region that must be transparent yourself.

One way I can think of doing this is to test all the pixels below a part of the user-drawn line and mark them as transparent until an intersection is met, and repeating this until the bottom of the image is reached.  See this drawing for reference:

[image]

ΔX here, is an arbitrarily-defined pixel length that can be either increased to improve accuracy, or decreased to improve performance.  The process of deriving this transparency would be as follows:

1. Obtain the value farthest to the left that is part of a vertex a user draws;
2. Progress down the image (by decreasing the value of `Y` in the `getPixel()` method until you collide with another user-drawn vertex, changing the pixels to transparent as you go using `setPixel()` and passing in your current coordinates;
3. When you collide with another vertex, stop changing the transparency of the pixels, but **continue** to parse down the column;
4. Again, if you reach another vertex, begin marking the following pixels as transparent;
5. Repeat this until you get to the bottom of the image;
6. Increment the X value by the constant ΔX that you predefined and repeat this on the next column.

Note that it is important that you toggle between setting the transparency and not setting transparency (you could use a `boolean` to maintain the state) as it is possible for polygons to "curve around" and come back into the column you are parsing.

Comment: But i can't understand everything about polygon.. i understood how make transparent rectangle. But if i have some collection of point (on image with width=100 and height=100) such as [(0,0); (10, 10); (50, 20); (80, 60); (20, 50); (0,0)], how it will be? can You make some little example about it? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you could clarify what your goals are here.  Would you like a user to be able to draw an arbitrary (N-sided) polygon, and then remove it from some PNG?  It is necessary that I know whether or not a user will be creating these polygons as the difficulty level of your question will increase dramatically if this is not the case (you could simply use the lines a user draws as a guide if it were the case).

Comment: I would like a user to be able to draw an arbitrary (N-sided) polygon, and then remove it from some PNG.

Comment: Thank You very much! It realy helps me! :)

Comment: If it answered your question, please mark as an answer by clicking the outlined check mark next to my answer, otherwise I'd be more than happy to clarify any further questions!